# Do Chinese universities accept NIOS certificate

Tags: distance-learning, india, china, russia

I am a former IT (Information Technology) professional from India. I have 5 years of experience in IT.

I am planning to join an MBBS course in China or Russia. I cannot pursue this in India because it very expensive and also there an age limit (candidate has to be less than 25 years).

My main problem is - While studying PUC (Equivalent to A-levels in UK and High School diploma in US) I opted out of Biology. Since I don't have biology in PUC, I cannot pursue MBBS.

I can remedy this situation by pursuing a distance education course in Biology from NIOS (National Institute of Open Schooling).

But I am afraid that Chinese/Russian universities might not accept a distance education course.

Can anyone please let me know if Chinese/Russian universities accept distance education courses for admission.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not send the department of the school you're considering an e-mail? There are so many universities in these two countries, even someone here went to a few, they may not be able to give you a 100% accurate answer. It's kind of a big deal, you don't want to land there and find out there is no school to attend. I'd suggest get to the very person for the answer.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86544/do-chinese-universities-accept-nios-certificate#comment218140_86544